# How do I compare types when using generics?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, c#-2.0

I am trying to derive the type of an object at runtime.  Specifically I need to know two things whether it implements ICollection or IDto.  Currently my only solution I have been able to find is this:

```
   private static bool IsACollection(PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        bool isCollection = false;

        foreach (Type type in descriptor.PropertyType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
                {
                    isCollection = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (type == typeof(ICollection))
                {
                    isCollection = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        return isCollection;
    }

    private static bool IsADto(PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        bool isDto = false;

        foreach (Type type in descriptor.PropertyType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (type == typeof(IDto))
            {
                isDto = true;
                break;
            }
        }          
        return isDto;
    }
```

However I am convinced there has to be a better way than this.  I have tried comparing in a normal fashion such as:

```
if(descriptor.PropertyType == typeof(ICollection<>))
```

However, this fails when using reflection yet when not using reflection it works fine.

I don't want to iterate through the interfaces for every field of my entity.  Could someone shed some light on another method in which to do this?  Yes, I am prematurely optimizing, but it looks ugly too so please humor me.

Caveats:

1. It could or could not be generic, such as IList<> or just ArrayList thus why I am looking for ICollection or ICollection<>.  So I assume I should use IsGenericType in an if statement to know whether to test using ICollection<> or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This:

```
type == typeof(ICollection)
```

will check if the type of property is *exactly* `ICollection`. That is, it will return true for:

```
public ICollection<int> x { get; set; }
```

but not for:

```
public List<int> x { get; set; }
```

If you want to check if the type of property is, *or is derived from*, `ICollection`, the simplest way is to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom`:

```
typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(type)
```

and the same goes for generic:

```
typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

Comment: Actually he is going through the entire hierarchy. Additionally, ICollection<> does not implement ICollection directly.

Comment: This did it, I had the order of these commands reversed!  I was doing typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection<>).  Thank you very much!

Comment: This did not work for me.  I had to post [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18937119/122781).

Answer (score 2):

Does `type.IsAssignable` help in this case?

EDIT: Sorry, it should have been `Type.IsAssignableFrom`

Comment: Unfortunately no.  When I check property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(ICollection<>) and the type is an IList<> it still fails.  Thank you though.