# typeof( ICollection<> ).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom( typeof(IList<>) )

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, reflection

I am trying to check the following

```
typeof( ICollection<> ).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom( targetProperty.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo() )
```

where the argument passed into `IsAssignableFrom` is an `IList<Something>`.  But it is returning false.

The following also returns false.

```
typeof( ICollection<> ).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom( targetProperty.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericTypeDefinition() )
```

Even the following is returning false.

```
typeof( ICollection<> ).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom( typeof(IList<>) )
```

Shouldn't the latter definitely return true?

How can I get the correct result when `targetProperty.PropertyType` can be any type at all?  It could be a `List<T>`, an `ObservableCollection<T>`, a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, a custom collection type, etc.

Comment: My first question was answered below, and my second is [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1075059/122781).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two open generic types. `IsAssignableFrom` interprets these like asking whether `ICollection<T1>` is assignable from `IList<T2>`. This is, in general, false. It is only true when T1 = T2. You need to do something to close the generic types with the same type argument. You could fill in the type as `object` or you could get the generic parameter type and use that:

```
var genericT = typeof(ICollection<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]; // a generic type parameter, T.
bool result = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(genericT).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(genericT)); // willl be true.
```

It seems `GetGenericArguments` is not available in PCL, and its behavior is different than `GenericTypeArguments` property. In a PCL you need to use `GenericTypeParameters`:

```
var genericT = typeof(ICollection<>).GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters[0]; // a generic type parameter, T.
bool result = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(genericT).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(genericT).GetTypeInfo()); // willl be true.
```

Comment: I get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` on `typeof( ICollection<> ).GenericTypeArguments[0]`.

Comment: `typeof( ICollection<> ).GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeParameters` works, though.

Comment: @HappyNomad `GenericTypeArguments` returns an empty array for generic type definitions. That is why I used `GetGenericArguments()`.

Comment: @HappyNomad I see `GetGenericArguments` is not available in PCL. I updated with a PCL compliant sample.

Comment: But why does typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ICollection<int>)) also returns false?

Answer (score 1):

`ICollection<T1>` cannot be assigned from `IList<T2>` *in general*; otherwise, you could end up with situations where you assign, say, a `List<char>` to an `ICollection<bool>`.

```
typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList<>))          // false
typeof(ICollection<bool>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<int>))    // false
```

You *can*, however, assign `ICollection<T>` from `IList<T>`, provided that the type parameter `T` is the same.

```
typeof(ICollection<bool>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<bool>))   // true
```

Starting from C# 4, this also works for type covariance:

```
typeof(IEnumerable<BaseClass>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<DerivedClass>)));         
    // true in C# 4
    // false in prior verions
```

Similarly, you can assign non-generic base interfaces from any generic type that implements them:

```
typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<bool>))         // true
```